# Enlarging font size changes color to white and remains unchangable

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

After enlarging the font size to more than 160px in tkinter the font color changes to white and remains unchangable. Why?

```
hl=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=("verdana",160))
hl.config(fg="black")
ml=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=("verdana",80))
sl=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=("verdana",80))
```

And produces like this output below:

[image: Output]

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on windows...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        hl=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=("verdana",160))
        hl.config(fg="black")
        hl.pack()
        ml=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=("verdana",80))
        ml.pack()
        sl=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=("verdana",80))
        sl.pack()

root = Tk()
my_gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLiwG.jpg)

Comment: But i use ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try the above code? It should work just as well on Ubuntu.

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: try    
        LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 160)
        SMALL_FONT = ("Verdana", 80)
        hl=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=LARGE_FONT)
        hl.pack()
        ml=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=SMALL_FONT)
        ml.pack()
        sl=tk.Label(root,text="12",font=SMALL_FONT)
        sl.pack()